# Hide and Unhide a range of rows based on the value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

Very Basic I am sure but I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I have a set of radio buttons that changes the value of cell("L37") between 1 and 2.

I have tried to write the VBA code several different ways without luck. Please advise.

```
Sub hide_sheet()
    If Worksheets("Feedback").Range("L37").Value = 1 Then
      Rows("63:93").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Else Worksheets("Feedback").Range("L37").Value = 2 Then
      Worksheets("Feedback").Rows("63:93").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
End Sub
```

I had it working perfectly fine via a Macro tied to the radio buttons; however, due to me needing to protect the sheet I needed to change it.

I am using a protect/unprotect VBA code and would like to include it into the code so it won't set off the macro/sheet protected warning.

Here is my protect/unprotect code I am using for everything.

```
Sub unprotect()

    Worksheets("Feedback").unprotect
    
End Sub

Sub protect()

    Worksheets("Feedback").protect , _
        AllowFormattingCells:=True, _
        AllowFormattingRows:=True
        
    
End Sub
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I Thank You in Advance of your assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Show/Hide Rows

**Issues**

- The `Feedback` worksheet is not qualified so if the wrong workbook is active, it will fail. To reference the workbook containing this code, you can use `ThisWorkbook`:

  ```
  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feedback")...
  ```
- You are using `Rows("63:93")` instead of `Worksheets("Feedback").Rows("63:93")` in the If clause. If the wrong worksheet is active (selected), it will fail.
- You are using `Else` instead of `ElseIf`.
- You can use the `With` statement to reduce typing as illustrated in the following code.
- If you convert the cell value to a string, then if the cell accidentally contains an error value, the code will not fail.

**The Code**

```vb
Sub ShowHideRowsFix()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feedback")
        .Unprotect
        Select Case CStr(.Range("L37").Value)
        Case "1"
            .Rows("63:93").Hidden = True
        Case "2"
            .Rows("63:93").Hidden = False
        Case Else
        End Select
        .Protect AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

**An Improvement**

- To automate this operation (no need for buttons), in the sheet module of the `Feedback` worksheet identified in the VBE Project explorer window by e.g. `Sheet1(FeedBack)` (double-click to open), you could use the following code.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const CellAddress As String = "L37"
    
    Dim Cell As Range: Set Cell = Me.Range(CellAddress)
    If Intersect(Cell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ShowHideRows Cell

End Sub

Sub ShowHideRows(ByVal Cell As Range)
    With Cell.Worksheet
        .Unprotect
        Select Case CStr(Cell.Value)
        Case "1"
            .Rows("63:93").Hidden = True
        Case "2"
            .Rows("63:93").Hidden = False
        Case Else
        End Select
        .Protect AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the simplest approach where possible. This is the approach I use to hide columns re-written for your needs.

The following code may exist on the UserForm or in a standard Code Module:

```
Sub rwControl(ByRef hType As String)
  Dim rwVis As Boolean
  If hType = "hRW" Then rwVis = True
  If hType = "uRW" Then rwVis = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Feedback")
      .Unprotect
      .Rows("63:93").Hidden = rwVis
      .Protect
    End With
End Sub
```

You may call this code directly from you RadioButton_Change() Event vy including the following code:

```
IF RadioButton1.Value = True then 'Assuming the value is 1
   rwControl "hRW"   'This hides the Rows
 ELSE
   rwControl "uRW"   'This unhides the Rows
End If
```

**OR**, to keep it really simple:

in your `RadioButton_Change()` event simply add:

```
Private Sub RadioButton1 Change()
With ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Feedback")
    .Unprotect
        If RadioButton1.Value = True Then
            .Rows("63:93").Hidden = True
          Else
            .Rows("63:93").Hidden = False
        End If
      .Protect
End With
End Sub
```

Using this approach negates the need for `Worksheet Module Coding` and `Case Coding` and allows you to keep the `RadioButtons` if you deem them important to the functionality.